# Código JS não se apresenta clicável em dispositivos móveis

Tags: javascript, html

Esse código JS nao fica clicável em dispositivos moveis. so em desktop. Alguem poderia me ajudar:

bloguer de teste
https://programarpostagem.blogspot.com.br/2017/10/strange-todos-os-episodios-formato.html

codigo js

```
$(function() {

  var videohtml5 = $('.videoGallery .videohtml5');
  var liHeight = $('.videoGallery li').height();

  // BLOGGER
  videohtml5.click(function() {
    var videoID = $(this).attr('data-videoID');
    var videos = '<div class="meuVideo"><center> <video width="100%" controls="controls" autoplay="true" poster="https://i.imgur.com/SoclbRY.png" src="https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=' + videoID + '" type="video/mp4"></video></center> </div>';

    // Abro uma janela popup
    video_popup = window.open("pagina_da_popup.html","video_popup","width=400, height=200");

    $('.meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();

    // Insiro os dados na popup
    video_popup.document.write(videos);

  });

  // Fechar Videos
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('.meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();
  });

})
```

Comment: é possível que o caminho não esteja sendo interpretado pelo navegador do celular com a mesma precisão do navegador PC, vc teria como implementar um ID ao invés da classe relacionada ao objeto.[exe: #meuvideoXPTO]

Comment: amigo. nao entendo nada de programacao . sei so um basico do basico..

Comment: se vc pode editar o codigo ficarei grato

Comment: alguem pra ajudar..

Comment: qual plugin vc está utilizando para exibir o vídeo?